How exactly I set a folder to not to inherit permission from parents but make sure all the children inherit from it in Windows?

I have a folder. Let's call it MyFolder in drive D.
I want D:\MyFolder to NOT inherit from D:. However I want all subfolders and files from D:\MyFolder to DO INHERIT from D:\MyFolder
Really simple right?
I want a special property for that folder. That is I only want coding, a username, to be able to access that. I do not want to enable free user to be able to access that folder.
So in Windows I have a bunch of users. One of it is called “Coding.” The computer name is “VideoGame.” So you see Owner: coding (VideoGame\coding) there.
I want that user to be the only user that can access that folder. Not other users.
So clearly MyFolder doesn’t inherit anything from the parents.
In “Permission Entries” it shows that coding has “Full Control.” Also that issue is inherited from None. It applies to This folder, subfolders and files.
Now there is a button disable inheritance.
That doesn't make sense.
If MyFolder doesn't inherit anything from the parents that means inheritance is disabled already on MyFolder. So how come I have a button saying disable inheritance?
Then, I got a checkbox saying replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object.
I think, if I understand correctly, that's what I want.
So D:\MyFolder DOES NOT inherit from D:\. However, I want ALL files and subfolders of D:\MyFolder to simply inherit permissions from D:\Myfolder.
So should I click disable inheritance?
What does that button do? Disable inheritance for D:\MyFolder? However, D:\MyFolder already DO NOT inherit from D:\ So why do I have a button saying Disable Inheritance? It doesn't make sense.

Update: After I disabled inheritance this is what I got on folder; D:\MyFolder\Dropbox for example
Dropbox doesn't work. Onedrive doesn't work btw.

To the left you see that coding has no permission whatsoever.
To the right you see that coding has full control of D:\MyFolder\Dropbox however that applies to only this folder so only to "D:\MyFolder\Dropbox" and not to it's subfolder.
Which is weird as hell.
I want D:\MyFolder\Dropbox AND ALL OF it's children to inherit from D:\MyFolder\
Is this what's going on right now?
Also if I check D:\MyFolder\ permissions I see this

Notice that replace all child permission with inheritable permission is not checked.
If I check replace all child permission with inheritable permission from this object I got error:

So I think that's exactly what I want.
I want:

D:\MyFolder to have a special permission. Namely that coding have full control of it and no one else does
I want every subfolders of D:\MyFolder to simply inherit permissions from D:\MyFolder

But if I do that I got failed to enumerate objects in the container. So what should I have done then?

Please paste into a code box the output of icacls D:\MyFolder. Simplest way to fix: For D:\MyFolder, either re-enable then re-disable it receiving inherited permissions from D: (gets things back to a fresh starting point), or manually add those permissions, and for either way, manually change all of them to sub folders and files only for D:, manually add the user/groups for accessing the root of D:\MyFolder (depending on ACLs, one user may have two entries), tick the box to apply it to child objects, then apply. System & Administrators should have access

(Cont’d…) I’m not on a Windows machine at the moment, but when programs require access to directories, they sometimes have to have the requisite ACLs for their directories (e.g. this may be why there’s an issue with OneDrive and DropBox - their ACLs must match what they were before you made changes). At worst, you’d need to sign out of both, then re-set them both up, choosing the custom folder during setup, to have the correct ACLs applied if they’re not known.

What is ACL?
This is a very simple task. I want a folder, namely D:\MyFolder to have a different permission and I want all D:\MyFolder children to simply inherit D:\MyFolder permission

ACL is the list of permissions entries. Are you currently logged in as VideoGame\coding in your screenshots? You do need to disable inheritance on the first folder. You can force enable inheritance on all the folders below it by checking the 'Replace all child' box, but it's not always necessary. The error in your screenshot says that the current user (coding?) does not have permission to read dropbox.cache, so you may need to exclude that folder. Software like dropbox/onedrive tend to manage file permissions themselves depending on how they're configured, and may "correct" your changes

@user4951 Following the steps in my first comment will set the permissions the way you want - System and the Administrators group still need full control to D:\MyFolder and all subfolders and files. There is no use case for disabling either’s ACLs, and it’s pointless to anyways since opening an Admin terminal will allow taking ownership and accessing its root, files, and subdirectories

You WANT Inheritance applied at the right place, and NOT applied at the wrong place.
You DON'T want the D drive permissions to apply to MyFolder, so disable inheritance on D drive.
You DO want everything inside MyFolder to get permissions you have set on MyFolder, so enable inheritance on MyFolder.
It may be necessary to grant the Coding user traversal or list folders permissions on D drive, but it may not be. Trying things first without setting this.
Given the scenario you have described, this is the solution.

Wait a minute. So inheritance need to be disabled at D drive? That's weird. I want all other folders in D drive to inherit from D drive. Just not MyFolder

Your question clearly states "I want D:\MyFolder to NOT inherit from D:. However I want all subfolders and files from D:\MyFolder to DO INHERIT from D:\MyFolder". THAT is set by DISABLING inheritance at D: and ENABLING inheritance at MyFolder. Simple as that. If that is NOT your question, then please rewrite your question to clearly state what your need actually is.

@user4951 did this solve your question? If so, please mark it as such. If it did not, please make your question more clear so that we can answer it.
